# How to pass compile flags to cl.exe from pip install?

Tags: python, windows, pip, cl.exe

I'm trying to install a local python package via pip install. It contains CPP files that require my compiler (Windows, cl.exe) to receive the /utf-8 flag.

How do I have to modify my command

```
pip install .
```

such that cl.exe is run with the /utf-8 flag?

The specific error, during compilation is

> src/phoneme_ids.cpp(187): error C2015: too many characters in constant
> cl.exe failed with exit code 2